# New router appears to be blocking my website locally

Tags: router, routing, iis, web-hosting

I recently upgraded my internet and with it, they installed a new router. For some reason, I cannot access my website locally anymore. If I open Chrome and go to https://www.example.com it comes back with "Site cannot be reached". The website is being hosted on my server, which is also on my same network (different computer). All of the ports have been forwarded, like they should be. None of the computers on my network can access my websites that I'm hosting. If I go to a computer outside my network, my sites come up just fine. Also, if I modify my HOSTS file and add:

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

Everything works fine again. However, I feel this is just a workaround for a different issue.

I am assuming it's a router issue because the new router is the only change made. No updates or software updates occurred. The new router is a Hitron CODA 5712. I am assuming there is just a security option I need to turn off or something to make it work again.

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Look up "NAT loopback" (also known as hairpinning). Your new router probably doesn't support it.

Comment: There is nothing strange about a Hitron (I have one here). Your DNS would likely have changed. Had you made a DNS accommodation in the prior modem setup?

Comment: without the host file hack, does dns lookup work for your domain name? if so, and you are getting the public IP of router, then n8te's diagnosis is likely correct. in that case, you need to be accessing your site/services using the LAN IP when you are within the lan. That said though, have you verified that DNS is responding with the actual public IP for your router? it will likely need to be updated. also do you really mean 127.0.0.1 or is there a real lan IP in there?

Comment: DNS is working. If I ping my site, it's resolving to the correct IP Address.

Comment: I went through all my settings and I did not see a setting for NAT Loopback, so I'm assuming my router doesn't support it and that's the issue.

Comment: A potential solution to this would be a local DNS server that directs requests for your local website to the correct computer and sends all other requests upstream. Your router would need to be set to use this DNS server.